# How to free the call stack in C?

Tags: c, stack, callstack, goto, setjmp

I have created a calculator using RDP (recursive descent parser) to parse and evaluate mathematical expressions "such as: 5*cos(30) -5*(3+5)". The thing is I also have tried to include commands like "config" which lets the user configure the angle units (Gra, Rad, Deg). And here I found a problem with the design of the code.

Simplified example of the **call stack**:

```
int main()
{
   parseexpr()
    {
       parseterm()
       {
          parsefactor()
          {
              parsecommand() or parsefct() or parsenumber();
          }

       }
    }
}
```

Now when the user inputs the "config" command. I would want to let him configure the calculator (the configuration is inside a .txt file) and just jump back to "main()" (where he would be asked to enter expression again) since it would be problematic to return through the call stack, as I would need a return value, which "parsecommand()" cannot return.

My question is how can I clean the call stack such that I would return to main directly through a "goto" statement ?

Comment: In a well-designed program, each function would return to the previous with a result code (enum etc). Therefore it is common practice to always reserve the return code of a function for a result/error state variable, and pass other return values through pointer parameters. There are evil ways to make a poorly-designed program (spaghetti programming with `setjmp`) but they are highly discouraged.

Comment: You do not use a goto statement. You simply return from each function until execution is once again at the main function.

Comment: Instead of forcing a function to return a value indicating a result, you could make it return a status code that specifies whether the operation was successful and yielded a result, or whether the function was aborted (for example due to a reconfiguration request by the user). If the operation was successful, then the function could return the result by other means than a return value, for example by writing to a variable whose address was passed to the function. That way, it is possible for all functions on the call stack to return the code for "operation aborted", until `main` is reached.

Comment: this should be properly achieved with `setjmp`; the call stack can't be freed without black magic.

Comment: @mcendu It cannot be _properly_ achieved with `setjmp`. It can be messily achieved with `setjmp`. I posted an answer explaining why.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel -- or OP functions could return structs that contain a status code member and a result member. The caller could then check the status code before proceeding.

Answer (score 7):

> My question is how can I clean the call stack such that I would return to main directly through a "goto" statement ?

Don't do that. That's actually a so-called "XY question".

The correct way to go about it is this:

- Place all these functions in a module of their own, lets call it `parse.h / parse.c`.
- In `parse.h` come up with a result/error type to be used by all applicable functions in this module. Something like:

  ```c
  typedef enum
  {
    /* whatever results that may make sense: */
    PARSE_OK,
    PARSE_BAD_FORMAT,
    PARSE_DIV_BY_ZERO,
    ...
  } parse_result_t;
  ```
- Applicable functions are then defined as:

  ```
  parse_result_t parse_expr (/* parameters */);
  ```

  Where any values that need to be returned are passed as pointer parameters.
- In a nested number of function calls, each function will check the result and if not OK, return an error code to the caller. Often it is considered good practice to not modify the value parameters upon error.

---

The incorrect, very bad practice alternative is to utilize `setjmp`/`longjmp` which are low level functions actually storing and restoring the callstack and other similar variables. So it's theoretically possible to do in standard C, but these functions are bad practice because:

- In a properly designed program, each function has no clue of who called it. It only knows which functions it will call itself. A properly designed program is a tree dependency structure with main() at the very top.
- Providing information of *why* something failed through a result variable enables various error checking/handling rather than just "oops something went wrong".
- By using return values rather than a global state variable, the functions are thread-safe and self-contained.
- By making the functions self-contained, there is no "tight coupling" to unrelated functions or variables. For example if I pick up your parse library, I don't want some strange linker error referring to some `jmp_buf` global variable being missing, which I'm then somehow supposed to implement in main(). Or worse yet: in order to link `parse.c` I must also link `main.c`. Such tight coupling dependencies are neither portable nor maintainable, it's bad in almost every imaginable way.
- Non-conditionally jumping to unrelated parts of the program has been considered bad programming since the 1960s ("GoTo Considered Harmful") and is referred to as "spaghetti programming" - the analogy being that your program will start to resemble a plate of spaghetti, where one strand might end up elsewhere at some unexpected, unrelated location. Incredibly difficult to read and maintain.
- `setjmp`/`longjmp` come with a long list of hazards and potential undefined behavior.

Comment: Probably the most sound use of `setjmp` and `longjmp` are for handling exceptional conditions -- this is notably the pattern used by libpng.

Comment: @mcendu I'll probably insist that there exist no proper use of `setjmp`/`longjmp` what-so-ever. Exception handling, as seen in some higher level languages, is nowadays widely recognized as a very bad idea to use. The only thing that would be worse than actually using for example C++ exceptions, would be to emulate such in C using `setjmp`/`longjmp`...

Comment: As for whatever patterns are used in various open source projects, yeah there often exists a whole lot of rotten anti-patterns in such projects... just look at Linux, it's the anti-pattern museum. Still it works fine - just don't peek under the hood!

Comment: The one place I can think of where `setjmp` and `longjmp` might be useful is unit testing functions which call `exit` or otherwise don't return.

Comment: @dbush Yeah obviously there can be uses for them outside production code. I remember utilizing them when demonstrating that clang can't generate infinite loops properly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59928620/584518).

Comment: Recursive descent parsers are actually one of the most common applications for `setjmp` / `longjmp`, specifically because having an explicit error return path in each of the numerous almost identical parser functions is way too tedious.  So I don't quite see the problem.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for speedy answer. My functions are designed in such a way that each one of them takes a "parsetree", modifies it and returns it to the calling function(which is also a parsing function). This way I cannot tell the functions to return parse_result_t. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Achraf -- you could pass a pointer to `parse_tree_t` and modify it through the pointer, returning a `parse_result_t`, or you could return the status code and the `parse_tree_t` together in a struct, e.g., something like `typedef struct { parse_result_t result; parse_tree_t tree; } parse_t;`, unwrapping the `parse_t` struct in the caller to inspect the `result` field before using the value in the `tree` field.

Comment: @fuz It's hard to comment on that without a concrete example. But generally: if I as a consumer order a car from a car salesman, then suddenly get a call from the car manufacturer in Japan, telling me in Japanese that the factory is out of screws... then just what am I supposed to do with that information? I can't solve the problem nor do I even understand Japanese. Should I cancel the order? Why are they calling me for and not the screw retailer providing screws to the factory?

Comment: @Lundin I don't get your analogy, sorry.  OP is writing a recursive descent parser, and these are often designed to use `setjmp` to back out of conditions were the parser cannot proceed as usual.  No problem here and there's no point in scaring OP about his programming style being wrong.

Comment: @fuz Is there an obvious reason to suspect that the call stack function calls aren't actually inlined here? The other reason to use setjmp would be some strange manual optimization where inlining failed and someone is scared of a few extra return instructions...

Comment: @Lundin Parsers are generally recursive in non-trivial ways, so inlining is not really an option.  Have you written a recursive-descent parser before?

Comment: @fuz I've written parsers and expression tree stuff, yes. It's very tempting to use tree structures for them since on the algorithm level it makes things easy. However, there's a bunch of practical problems with recursion and many strong arguments against using it in practice. But if you boil it down, you are really just after the stacking feature and that one could be implemented separately. Anyway, there's not one single good solution to any programming problem and even evil stuff like setjmp and recursion are just tools - there may be places even for them in some specialized scenarios.

Comment: @Lundin You're changing the topic here; I'm specifically talking about recursive descent parsers (which is what OP writes), not other types of parsers or techniques to implement them.  Also as far as your “many strong arguments” are concerned, it would be interesting to hear some of them.  Many important compilers use recursive descent parsers and they work just fine.  There does not seem to be anything wrong with the approach, including with jumping out of the recursion with longjmp.

Comment: @fuz Recent post about the many problems of recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77745602/584518.

Comment: @Lundin You mention one (not many) problem, namely, that stack space can run out.  For many parser applications, that's acceptable.

Comment: @fuz I don't know of any application where running out of stack space is acceptable... Also it is mentioned that recursion optimizes poorly, since it doesn't necessarily get inlined unless tail call, if even then.

Comment: I think I'm just giving up here.  Inlining is irrelevant as you need the call stack to save the state of your parse tree.  By construction you want a chain of stack frames, inlining is clearly impossible but also irrelevant and not needed here.  I am not sure why you keep pointing this out.  And yes, running out of stack space is acceptable for many applications like compilers.  Those programs would crash anyway when the nesting depth is exceeded.  If they do so with a stack fault or with some other error message is irrelevant.  Note also that you can of course handle this case if you want.